# JavaCode To Connect API Mgr Using Client Id/Client Secret/Token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a BE Java Service, which is RESTFul, which is ported on WSO2 API Manager. It is published and available in Store. I have registered a new Application (by Name ' Java App ') and upon subscribing to that API, it provided me with Client Key and Client Secret along with Token. Using the Token I am able to successfully access the API (from SOAP UI). My requirement is to access the API from a standalone Java Application. Can someone direct me or provide appropriate code that can access the published API.

Regards, Sreedhar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to invoke the API by sending `Authorization` as a HTTP Header.

```
String url = "API_URL";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add Authorization Header header
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer :" + accessToken);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

For Generating Token with username, password and Client Key / Secret, You can use following cURL sample to build the HTTP request. More information can be found in [token api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Generating+Access+Tokens+with+User+Credentials+-+Password+Grant+Type)

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

You have to base 64 encode Client Key / Secret and send it with Authorization header as Basic.

Comment: Hi Abhiram, Thanks for sharing the code snippet. I used the code, however ran into some SSL problems, which were resolved. However, when accessing from the code, I am getting 401 (Unauthorized) code. On API Manager console following two logs are populated. 1. [2016-06-01 11:20:22,918]  INFO - APIKeyValidator Invalid OAuth Token : Access Token : expired.
2. [2016-06-01 11:20:22,924]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials.  Note that I am able to successfully hit from SOAP UI using same token also from API Console.

Comment: Further, I am looking for code that uses the Client Key / Secret to obtain a fresh token then use it in access. It would be a great help if you forward such code too.

Comment: It's said in the log, ` Access Token : expired`, generate a new token and try. There are two gateway URL, one is through HTTPS and other one is through HTTP, you need to use HTTP, otherwise you need to setup keystore/truststore in your client side.

Comment: Well, I found what is the issue. When sending the value for 'Authorization', in the code we are sending 'Bearer : <token>'.  There is a COLON that is there extra. When I removed and got a 200 response Code.

Comment: Abhiram, if you could send token generation code too, it would be a great help. Regards.

Comment: @sreedhar, I have updated the answer with information

Comment: @AbimaranThe CURL is resulting in OutOfMemory Error. GC Overhead limit exceeded.

Comment: What's your memory allocation?

Comment: Everything is default. Can we change and if so, what is the impact.

Comment: There shouldn't be an OOM issue. Yea, you can increase

Comment: @Abhimaran:I tried even increasing the heap size. Same problem. No clue whats happening. Is it a Bug ?